# Regex to get some values from an input string

Tags: php, regex

Having the following input string:

```
"health status index              pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
yellow  open   first_index          5   1     222173            0     43.8gb         43.8gb 
green   open   second_index         5   1      27131            7     36.6gb         36.6gb 
red     open   third_index          5   1       4047            0     22.4mb         22.4mb 
"
```

How can I get the following output string, which takes the first column, `health` and the 3rd one, `index`?

```
"first_index - yellow, first_index - green, third_index - red"
```

Thanks in advance.

PS: The `index` names can vary and have no `_index`. The example above all of them have `_index` but there can be indexes without any `_index`. The values of `status` can vary too.

Comment: Is there a reason why this would be a string and not an array?

Comment: An array is ok too.

Comment: **If** you have the choice to save this as an array or string, I would recommend saving this as an array. If this comes from an external source and you cant have it as an array, then ignore me.

Comment: s `first_index - green` a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among others, this will work:

```
^(\w+)\W+\w+\W+(\w+)
```

Take group `\2` and `\1`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/m0Oepx/1/) (and mind the `MULTILINE` modifier).

---

As `PHP` code ([**demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/ElVzTw)):

```
<?php

$string = <<<DATA
health status index              pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
yellow  open   first_index          5   1     222173            0     43.8gb         43.8gb 
green   open   second_index         5   1      27131            7     36.6gb         36.6gb 
red     open   third_index          5   1       4047            0     22.4mb         22.4mb 
DATA;

$regex = '~^(\w+)\W+\w+\W+(\w+)~m';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
   echo $match[2] . "-" . $match[1] . "\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex with 2 captured groups in `preg_match_all` function:

```
/^(\S+)\h+\S+\h+(\S+)/m
```

You can then take capture group-2 and capture group-1 to format your output.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7JayTS/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do the job:

```
$str = "health status index              pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
yellow  open   first_index          5   1     222173            0     43.8gb         43.8gb 
green   open   second_index         5   1      27131            7     36.6gb         36.6gb 
red     open   third_index          5   1       4047            0     22.4mb         22.4mb 
";

preg_match_all('/\R(\w+)\h+\w+\h+(\w+)/', $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
yellow  open   first_index
            [1] => 
green   open   second_index
            [2] => 
red     open   third_index
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => yellow
            [1] => green
            [2] => red
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => first_index
            [1] => second_index
            [2] => third_index
        )

)
```